# linear combination of RTT and bandwidth

Tags: networking, network-programming

Maybe it's a stupid question!

Assume a P2P network in which peers independently try to find and connect to good nodes.
good nodes are those that are closer(in term of RTT) and has higher bandwidth.
in this scenario RTT is more important (for example RTT has 90% weight).

I want  to obtain the **liner combination of RTT and bandwidth** in a meaningful way.
but it's obvious that the nature of these two metric is inconsistent.
How can I combine these two metrics ?

Comment: 'Liner'? Do you mean 'linear'?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: dear EJP, yes , linear :)

Comment: John, I'm working on a protocol for overlay construction using C++ based simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key unicast routing protocols (it is a point to point and not P2P), EIGRP, uses several metrics to come up with a single metric. EIGRP is a very popular routing protocol. Delay (aka RTT) and bandwidth are typically the two key params for EIGRP. So, your questions is a relevant one!

This should help:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6554/ps6599/ps6630/whitepaper_C11-720525.html

Given the nature of bandwidth and delay, you could have multiple peers scoring the same final metric. For example, you could have one peer, P1, with values B and D. and another peer, P2, with values 2B and 2D. Assuming the bandwidth represents the capacity of the pipe, you would be able to transport a given amount of data with both of these peers in the same time!

You should certainly use a default value of weights, let us say, 0.50/0.5, for these two params. But, you might find that for a given goal (faster routing convergence, say), a different value of weights might be better.

Comment: Thank You Manoj for your answer.
I think there is a misunderstanding,
BW is a node-based metric in my case(up link bandwidth of peers ),not an edge-based one.
am i right ?

anyway, I'm working on EIGRP. it's interesting.

Comment: Btw, Cisco has recently released an IETF draft for EIGRP. You might find that useful: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-savage-eigrp-00